# What is the BSON doc (query) for the cmd `show dbs` in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

According to [Getting Started with MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/), we can use `show dbs` to get the list of existing databases.

But this is a kind of command running in the `mongo shell`.

**My question** is that how to write a `mongodb query (bson)` for the list of databases, and where this query should be sent to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a query, but you can run the `listDatabases` command against the admin database to get a list of databases in BSON:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.runCommand({listDatabases : 1})
{
        "databases" : [
                {
                        "name" : "local",
                        "sizeOnDisk" : 83886080,
                        "empty" : false
                },
        ],
        "totalSize" : 83886080,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Most programming language engines for MongoDB can also run commands in addition to queries given the right syntax.  For example, in Java:

```
DB db = mongo.getDB("admin");
DBObject cmd = new BasicDBObject("listDatabases", 1);
CommandResult result = db.command(cmd);
```

Interestingly, if you're really insistent on it being a query, you can query the virtual collection `$cmd` on the `admin` database to run commands by submitting queries:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.$cmd.findOne({"listDatabases":1})
```

Comment: Thanks. I am slowly writing a driver for mongodb, so I need to know this query, as actually every command is a query, right?

Comment: Not exactly.  [Database commands are non-CRUD operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/use-database-commands/).  But you can, interestingly, run commands by querying a virtual collection on the admin database:  `use admin`  `db.$cmd.findOne({"listDatabases":1})`.  [source](http://blog.rajatpandit.com/2011/12/23/notes-on-mongodb-quickstart-guide-to-mongodb/)

Comment: Thanks. If commands are non-crud (what is crud by the way?) operations, how can all those drivers handle? I mean, talking with MongoDB's wire protocol, only several operations are allowed, and there are no OP_COMMAND operation, right? How does driver talk commands to mongodb?

Comment: CRUD is "Create, Read, Update, Delete", the major functions of a database.

Comment: I just read up a little bit more on the wire protocol -- drivers send commands via OP_QUERY against the $cmd collection, which is why it's there.  :)  You have to be sure to [use limit -1 for findOne](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/44XZhno88QQ).